# Outgoing call ring, no ring status detect

Tags: android

I wish to detect That when an outgoing call is made the phone called is ringing or it is not ringing. I do not want for incoming call. Pls guide me how to capture the ringing state in outgoing calls. 
Thanks in Advance.